# Dynamic return type for .NET Method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a web method which calls a method in the DAL to execute a procedure by id and returns an object of type MyData.

```
[WebMethod]
public MyData GetDataById(int id)
{
    DAL myDAL = new DAL();
    return myDAL.GetDataById(id);
}
```

The class MyData looks like the following

```
public class MyData
{        
    public string Name;
    public Data[] DataItems;     
}
```

and the class `Data`,

```
public class Data
{
    public string key;
    public string value;
}
```

Now this worked fine for until we wanted to return a bit of complex types.

For an example, a `DataTable`, or perhaps something like a structure (or class) containing *latitude*, *longitude* and a *value*. So obviously, class `Data` cannot hold multiple values or a DataTable. (It contains two strings, key and value).

So what I actually want is the type to be Generic. So I changed it to...

```
public class MyData<T>
{        
    public string Name;
    public T[] DataItems;     
}
```

So I'll be doing something like this inside the `myDAL.GetDataById` because what type of data is returned differs according to the type.

```
if (GetTypeOfId(id) == "NormalData")
{
   MyData<Data> result = new MyData<Data>();
}
else if (GetTypeOfId(id) == "Map")
{
   MyData<MapData> result = new MyData<MapData>();
}
```

But I need to specify a type for the method signature as well which unfortunately is found out ONLY at run time.

How do I handle such a situation ?

I feel like I am using Generics for something I shouldn't be using it for.

Or how is usually a situation where the type is found out only at run time resolved?

**UPDATE:** The worst case scenario is having different web service calls for getting normal data and map data which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Which method do you need to specify the type for? Can't you do public MyData<T> GetDataById(int id) ?

Comment: Yes. For the web service call, as well the the method in the DAL.

Comment: @Cilvic: Can you really have a generic `WebMethod`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty easy and stupid of me not to think of it before.
I just created a parent class and made the `Data` and all the other required classes inherit from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use generics in circumstances where you can specify the type at compile time, so I don't think they're suitable for your situation.

I would recommend having two web service calls, that's the easiest way to handle this.

If you really want only one web service call you could have your web method simply return a byte[] (created using BinaryFormatter) or a string (created using, say, an XmlSerializer) and then deserialise that on your client side, but it means you have to have the same classes on both sides (or you have to have custom deserialisation code) and your web service can't easily be consumed by multiple clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking for but i have a feeling that using an interface with a generic method could help you pass return values around and call the GetValue generic method on that.

If you use IData instead of a generic type as return value you will be able to extract the embedded data with `ret.GetValue<MyData>()`. And if you set the Type when creating the `Data<T>` you will be able to query on that too.

Maybe you can adapt the following snippet to your needs.

```
public interface IData {
    type Type { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    T GetValue<T>();
}

public class Data<T> : IData
{

    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Tret GetValue<Tret>() {
        return (Tret)(Object)Value;
    }
}
```